# Is there a way to stack date and time vertically in Vaadins DateTimePicker component?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, vaadin14

For choosing some values of different data types in my UI, I use Vaadin's `DateTimePicker` introduced in 14.3.x.

I am wondering if I can somehow position date and time input fields vertically instead of horizontally? See the picture:

[image]

The DateTimePicker component is here simply to width horizontically. And I *don't* have the option to make all other inputs like the one for a string wider, too.

I have checked the [API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.3.7/com/vaadin/flow/component/datetimepicker/DateTimePicker.html) but there doesn't seem to be a stardard way of achieving the vertically stacking. Has anyone an idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's doable with CSS. In your Java class, add a CSS import annotation for the class something like follows:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/dtp.css", themeFor = "vaadin-date-time-picker")
public class MyView extends Div { 
//...
```

When creating the `DateTimePicker`:

```
        DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
        dateTimePicker.setClassName("stacked");
```

and in `/frontend/styles/dtp.css`:

```
:host(.stacked) .slot-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Vaadin 24, the setup for the accepted answer basically worked, I just needed to tweak the CSS:

```
:host(.stacked) .slots {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```